# Use teb local planner for turtlebot

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I want to use the teb local planner for the turtlebot instead of the dwa planner.
However, I am a bit confused about how to setup the navigation stack discussed on tutorial 3:
http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Configure%20and%20run%20Robot%20Navigation

According to the tutorial, one can use the teb planner by adding the following line to the move_base.launch file:

```
<param name="base_local_planner" value="teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS" />
```

However, even after doing so the published plan is "/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/local_plan". So I am confused about what I did wrong as I closely followed the tutorial. My custom launch file can be seen below:

```
<launch>

<include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/velocity_smoother.launch.xml"/> 

<arg name="odom_frame_id"   default="odom"/>
<arg name="base_frame_id"   default="base_footprint"/>
<arg name="global_frame_id" default="map"/>
<arg name="odom_topic" default="odom" />
<arg name="laser_topic" default="scan" />

<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" 
ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />   
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />   
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find teb_local_planner_tutorials)/launch/custom/dwa_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" /> 

    <param name="dwa_local_planner" value="teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS" />
    <param name="controller_frequency" value="5.0" />
    <param name="controller_patience" value="15.0" />

    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel"/> 
    <remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="$(arg laser_topic)"/>
</node>

</launch>
```

In order to load the map I have created a custom amcl launch file (modified version of amcl_demo.launch):

```
<launch>
 <!-- Map server -->
 <arg name="map_file" default="$(env TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_MAP_FILE)"/>
 <arg name="3d_sensor" default="$(env TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR)"/>  <!-- r200, kinect, asus_xtion_pro -->

 <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

 <!-- Localization -->
 <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/>
 <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/>
 <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>
 <arg name="custom_amcl_launch_file" default="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/amcl/$(arg 3d_sensor)_amcl.launch.xml"/> 

 <include file="$(arg custom_amcl_launch_file)">
 <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
 <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
 <arg name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
 </include>

<!-- teb -->
<include file="$(find teb_local_planner_tutorials)/launch/custom/turtle_teb.launch"/>
</launch>
```

To run Gazebo : "roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch",

AMCL:
"roslaunch teb_local_planner_tutorials amcl_teb.launch map_file:=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/maps/playground.yaml
"

The example itself ("roslaunch teb_local_planner_tutorials robot_diff_drive_in_stage.launch")  seems to work fine.
I would really appreaciate any help, as I have no idea on how to solve this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362110/use-teb-local-planner-for-turtlebot/) by [protoGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/59527/protoguy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of `<param name="dwa_local_planner" value="teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS" />` in your launch file you should have `<param name="base_local_planner" value="teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS" />`?

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [protoGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/59527/protoguy/) on 2020-09-24**:
Wow, thanks for the quick answer. I thought I have to use the dwa yaml file since the im using turtlebot 2 and the base planner was located in the turtlebot 3 folder. I initially thought you have to use the yaml file provided by the bot you are using ...

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-24**:
@protoGuy I am so glad I could help! So the [ROS parameter server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server) essentially stores variable name for you. So when you ran the command you previously had, it loaded the name "teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS" into a parameter on the server called "dwa_local_planner". But the parameter name `move_base` looks for is called "base_local_planner". So before there was no "base_local_planner" at all, but now if you fixed it, there should be a parameter in the `move_base` name space called `base_local_planner` with the value `teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS`.

To prove it, after the program launches you can run `rosparam list` and you should see all the available parameters in the parameter server. To get the value of "base_local_planner" you can probably just run  `rosparam get /move_base/base_local_planner`. Depending on namespaces the command might change a little, but that is a good start to understand the parameter server better.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-01-12**:
@jackB I have a related question where I am also trying to use the teb_local_planner with turtlebot3 [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/394095/unable-to-calibrate-teb_local_planner-for-path-planning/), if you could spare some time.